# Ultrasonic sensor, dc motor and sw420 in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, sensors

I am developing a system where I am avoiding an accident by slowing down the motor speed using distance provided by ultrasonic sensor. Also, if accident happens, it must be sense through sw420 and accident occurred result should be displayed.
The problem is that, i have code for both motor mgmt. - distance sensing and impact detection. But as I want them to run parallel i.e.., both are running at same time. How to do it?
Eg. If car is running smoothly, suddenly another car hits you from, let's say, from back.....then automatically, sw420 sensor should sense it and alert the accident occurred message. 
Or in other words, some type of multiprocessing concept is needed which i am unaware of.

Here's what i have done till now - 
1. Motor is perfectly slowing down when ultrasonic sensor senses shorter distance.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# Define GPIO For Driver motors
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
gpio.setwarnings(False)
gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)
gpio.setup(7,gpio.OUT)


pwm=GPIO.PWM(18,100)

# Define GPIO for ultrasonic central
GPIO_TRIGGER_CENTRAL = 23
GPIO_ECHO_CENTRAL = 24
GPIO.setup(GPIO_TRIGGER_CENTRAL, GPIO.OUT)  # Trigger > Out
GPIO.setup(GPIO_ECHO_CENTRAL, GPIO.IN)      # Echo < In




# Functions for driving


def goforward():
    pwm.start(100)
    GPIO.output(12, True)
    GPIO.output(16, False)
    GPIO.output(18, True)



def goforwardslow():

    GPIO.output(12, True)
    GPIO.output(16, False)
    GPIO.output(18, True)

def stopmotors():
    GPIO.output(12, False)
    GPIO.output(16, False)
    GPIO.output(18, False)


def buzzer():
try:
    while True:
            gpio.output(7,0)
            time.sleep(0.2)
            gpio.output(7,1)
            time.sleep(0.2)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
            gpio.cleanup()
            exit


#Detect front obstacle
def frontobstacle():

    # Set trigger to False (Low)
    GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER_CENTRAL, False)
    # Allow module to settle
    time.sleep(0.2)
    # Send 10us pulse to trigger
    GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER_CENTRAL, True)
    time.sleep(0.00001)
    GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER_CENTRAL, False)
    start = time.time()
    while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO_CENTRAL) == 0:
        start = time.time()
    while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO_CENTRAL) == 1:
        stop = time.time()
    # Calculate pulse length
    elapsed = stop - start
    # Distance pulse travelled in that time is time
    # Multiplied by the speed of sound (cm/s)
    distance = elapsed * 17150 # distance of both directions so divide by 2
    print "Front Distance : %.1f" % distance
    return distance



# Check front obstacle and stop  if there is an obstacle
def checkanddrivefront():
    while frontobstacle() < 15:
        pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(25)
       buzzer()
        goforwardslow()
time.sleep(3)
goforward()



# Avoid obstacles and drive forward
def obstacleavoiddrive():
    goforward()
    start = time.time()
    # Drive 5 minutes
    while start > time.time() - 300:  # 300 = 60 seconds * 5
        if frontobstacle() < 15:
            pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(25)
            goforwardslow()
            checkanddrivefront()
        #elif rightobstacle() < 30:
          #  stopmotors() 
           # checkanddriveright()
        #elif leftobstacle() < 30:
          #  stopmotors()
            #checkanddriveleft()


# Clear GPIOs, it will stop motors       
    #cleargpios()


#def cleargpios():
    #print "clearing GPIO"
    #GPIO.output(12, False)
    #GPIO.output(13, False)
    #print "All GPIOs CLEARED"


def main():
    # First clear GPIOs
    #cleargpios()
    print "start driving: "
    # Start obstacle avoid driving
    obstacleavoiddrive()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

2. Vibrations is also detecting by sw420

   import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
       from time import sleep

   ```
   channel = 17
   GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
   GPIO.setup(channel, GPIO.IN)
   sleep(0.1)

   while True:
           result = GPIO.input(channel)
           if result == 1:
               print ("Vibration")
   ```

Now the problem is that, where should i place or how can i use vibration/sw420 code in the MAIN CODE so that both run parallel and whenever accident happens, sw420'code occupies higher priority than motor code and gives accident occurred message.

Please share your advice.

**NOW THIS IS WHAT LATEST I HAVE DONE TILL NOW -**

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

# Define GPIO For Driver motors
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(7,GPIO.OUT)
pwm=GPIO.PWM(18,100)


channel = 11
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(channel, GPIO.IN)
sleep(0.1)




# Define GPIO for ultrasonic central
GPIO_TRIGGER_CENTRAL = 23
GPIO_ECHO_CENTRAL = 24
GPIO.setup(GPIO_TRIGGER_CENTRAL, GPIO.OUT)  # Trigger > Out
GPIO.setup(GPIO_ECHO_CENTRAL, GPIO.IN)      # Echo < In




# Functions for driving


def goforward():
    pwm.start(100)
    GPIO.output(12, True)
    GPIO.output(16, False)
    GPIO.output(18, True)



def goforwardslow():

    GPIO.output(12, True)
    GPIO.output(16, False)
    GPIO.output(18, True)

def stopmotors():
    GPIO.output(12, False)
    GPIO.output(16, False)
    GPIO.output(18, False)


def buzzer():
    while True:
            GPIO.output(7,0)
            time.sleep(0.2)
            GPIO.output(7,1)
            time.sleep(0.2)

def vib():

while True:
        result = GPIO.input(channel)
        if result == 1:
            print ("Vibration")




#Detect front obstacle
def frontobstacle():

    # Set trigger to False (Low)
    GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER_CENTRAL, False)
    # Allow module to settle
    time.sleep(0.2)
    # Send 10us pulse to trigger
    GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER_CENTRAL, True)
    time.sleep(0.00001)
    GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER_CENTRAL, False)
    start = time.time()
    while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO_CENTRAL) == 0:
        start = time.time()
    while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO_CENTRAL) == 1:
        stop = time.time()
    # Calculate pulse length
    elapsed = stop - start
    # Distance pulse travelled in that time is time
    # Multiplied by the speed of sound (cm/s)
    distance = elapsed * 17150 # distance of both directions so divide by 2
    print "Front Distance : %.1f" % distance
    return distance

# Check front obstacle and stop  if there is an obstacle
def checkanddrivefront():
    while frontobstacle() < 15:
        pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(25)
        buzzer()
        goforwardslow()
time.sleep(3)
goforward()



# Avoid obstacles and drive forward
def obstacleavoiddrive():
    goforward()
    start = time.time()
    # Drive 5 minutes
    while start > time.time() - 300:  # 300 = 60 seconds * 5
        if frontobstacle() < 15:
            pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(25)
            buzzer()
            goforwardslow()
            checkanddrivefront()
        #elif rightobstacle() < 30:
          #  stopmotors() 
           # checkanddriveright()
        #elif leftobstacle() < 30:
          #  stopmotors()
            #checkanddriveleft()


# Clear GPIOs, it will stop motors       
    #cleargpios()
#def cleargpios():
    #print "clearing GPIO"


def main():    
print "start driving: "
    # Start obstacle avoid driving
    obstacleavoiddrive()



if __name__ == "__main__":

    p1 = multiprocess.Process(target = main)

    p2 = multiprocess.Process(target = vib)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
```

I HAVE USED MULTIPROCESSING ....BUT YET AGAIN ONLY MOTOR DRIVE FUNCTION IS EXECUTING, VIBRATION CODE IS NOT ACTIVE IN THE CODE....means no output from it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to make this a [mcve], please! <3

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you making?

Comment: So it sounds like you have two classes at play here (despite the current implementation). One class that drives and one that handles an accident. You could either write the functions that deal with an accident happening in the same file or import the file where those functions exist. Then when an accident happens call the appropriate functions and either return in the method you came from or exit in the newly called vibration functions. This will allow your accident handling methods to "take over" when an accident happens.

Comment: Please refer to my edited part....i have tried multiprocessing, but no improvement yet.